# How to prove these two identities

Tags: combinatorics, infinite-product

> Show that
>   $$\begin{align}
> &\prod\limits_{k\ge 1}\frac{1-q^k}{1+q^k}=\sum \limits_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}(-1)^{n}q^{n^2}\tag{1}\\
> &\prod\limits_{k\ge 1}(1-q^k)^3=\sum \limits_{n\ge 0}(-1)^{n}(2n+1)q^{n(n+1)/2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

I have no idea of how to prove this two beautiful identity? I guess this two identity need help with Jacobi triple product?

Comment: Look at this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665167/)

Comment: 1) One question at a time. 2) Can we assume the Jacobi triple product ? 3) Do you want an algebriac or combinatorial proof ? 4) Your efforts ? blah blah.

Comment: My efforts is by use of Jocobi triple identity,but I have just touch upon on Jocobi identity, I fail to prove it. Thanks advance for your willing to share your idea.\

Answer (score 2):

The first one is given in [Prove these identities using Jacobi's triple product identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665167/prove-these-identities-using-jacobis-triple-product-identity)

As regards the second one, use again the [Jacoby triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) in the form
$$\prod_{n\geq1}(1-x^{2n})(1-yx^{2n+1})(1-y^{-1}x^{2n-1}) =\frac{1}{1-yx}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-y)^nx^{n^{2}},$$
and note that,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to x^{-1}}\left(\frac{1}{1-yx}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-y)^nx^{n^{2}}\right)&\stackrel{H}{=}
\lim_{y\to x^{-1}}\left(\frac{1}{-x}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n(-y)^{n-1}(-1)x^{n^{2}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-n)(-1)^{n}x^{n^{2}-n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n}x^{n^{2}+n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}x^{n^{2}-n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n}x^{n^{2}+n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(-1)^{n}x^{(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(2n+1)x^{n^{2}+n}.
\end{align}$$
Hence, by letting $y\to x^{-1}$ in the triple product, we get
$$\prod_{n\geq1}(1-x^{2n})(1-x^{2n})(1-x^{2n}) =\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(2n+1)x^{n^{2}+n}.$$
Finally replace $x$ with $q^{1/2}$.