# Gauss's Identities

Tags: combinatorics

So I have asked this question recently, and it is essentially the application of the Jacobi Triple Identity as the problem suggest we should use this, however there was an answer posted to the recent thread I made [Gauss identities of $q$-analog](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731910/gauss-identities-of-q-analog), but when I tried to study it carefully I still do not get the exact application of Jacobi's identity (I even saw the first equality somewhere on this forum [Prove these identities using Jacobi's triple product identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665167/prove-these-identities-using-jacobis-triple-product-identity), which seems somewhat satisfactory, however, the second equality I am still very much stuck), but the product terms involving thee $q$'s got me really confused) to get the results I want, which are:

> $$\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1-q^k}{1+q^k}=\sum_{{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}(-1)^nq^{n^2}$$
>   $$\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1-q^{2k}}{1-q^{2k-1}}=\sum_{n\ge0}q^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$$

Could anyone give me a clear step-by-step explanation of how to use the Jacobi triple product identity to prove the above results? I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JTP
$$\sum_n(-1)^nq^{n^2}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1})^2
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)(1-q^{2n-1})
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^n)^2}{1-q^{2n}}
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^n)^2}{(1-q^n)(1+q^n)}
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-q^n}{1+q^n}.
$$
Here I twice used
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1})
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n).$$

For the second one,
write
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{\binom{n+1}2}=\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty
q^{n/2}q^{n^2/2}$$
and then use JTP.

Comment: It all seems neat, but what I am confused with these product manipulations are, why is $(1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1})^2$ suddenly become $(1-q^n)(1-q^{2n-1})?$ also how can $\prod(1−q^{2n})(1−q^{2n−1})=\prod(1−q^n)$. Normal algebra tells me this cant be true. Which is why I am confused.

Comment: Look .... $\prod(1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1})=(1-q^2)(1-q)(1-q^4)(1-q^3)\cdots$ etc.

Comment: I just got it, divide it up in to odd and even sections then manipulating it, yes thank you finally got it.